# Dockerfile | accepts terms and conditions pressing enter

Tags: bash, docker

I'm creating a Dockerfile where I have to install a package with particular terms and conditions.

When I execute

```
apt-get install -y ros-crystal-rmw-connext-cpp
```

Then I have to "read" all the T&C by pressing ENTER to advance of one line.
There are 75 lines in total.

Once I get to the end, it asks me to input yes or no, which I should be able to do prepending the answer with the pipe command.

My problem is how to press enter 75 times or how to skip to the end of the terms and conditions ?

UPDATE: I tried piping some values

```
printf 'y\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\' | apt-get install ros-crystal-rmw-connext-cpp
```

However it looks like the `y` is accepted, but all the values required to skip the T&C are not working. Moreover when I use this structure I am not even able to input something manually and I have to exit from the process putting it in background with ctrl + z and then killing it.

Thank you

Comment: Dit you try `apt-get --yes --force-yes install ros-crystal-rmw-connext-cpp`?

Comment: What happens if you press SPACE instead of ENTER?

Comment: @veben your command doesn't work

Comment: @lxop cool, SPACE brings me to the end of the T&C!

Comment: How about `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ros-crystal-rmw-connext-cpp`

Comment: Ctrl+Z does not exit the process.

Comment: @emix It doesn't work.